# Make minus sign optional in Regex (AltoRouter 1.2.0)

Tags: php, regex, altorouter

I'm using AltoRouter 1.2.0 as a PHP router.

I'd like to use an optional parameter ('page'), and make a minus sign optional in the URL.

If page number is 2, URL should contain the thread ID and the page number, separated by a minus sign.

`/forum/24981-2/my-super-forum-thread`

If page number is one, the page parameter shouldn't be in the URL, and URL should be something like this

`/forum/24981/my-super-forum-thread` (no page number, no minus sign)

AltoRouter's optional parameters depend on this Regex, as you can see in [the doc](https://altorouter.com/usage/mapping-routes.html) :

```
''   => '[^/\.]++'
```

It makes the slash and the dot optional in the URL, it works as it should.
I'd like to make the minus sign optional as well.

My route declaration is currently like this

```php
$router->map('GET', '/forum/[i:thread_id]-[:page]?/[s:slug]', 'forum#getThread', 'forum_getThread');
```

I've tried a lot of different regex, like adding the minus sign at the beginning or end of the brackets, but no luck.

Any help is appreciated, i've checked a lot of questions on SO regarding the minus sign in regex, but couldn't make it.
Thanks in advance for any tip.

Comment: If you make the minus sign optional, how is the router supposed to know where the thread_id stops and the page starts?

Comment: @vixducis if I replace the minus sign with the dot or a slash, these special chars become optional when no page number is specified, according to the Regex I pasted. I just want this same behavior with the minus sign.

Comment: `[^/\.]++` doesn't make the slash and the dot "optional", it catches all until a slash or a dot or the end of the string. (as an aside, escaping a dot in a character class is useless).

Comment: Did you try something like `'/forum/[i:thread_id]-?[i:page]?/[s:slug]'` ?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for the help. I've just tried it, it didn't work. The minus sign is now followed by a question mark in the URL, that's all.

Comment: Ok, in this case, record your own match type (lets say cOh for *custom Optional hyphen*) before to deal with this optional hyphen (as described in the manual): `$router->addMatchTypes(array('cOh' => '-?'));` and then use `'/forum/[i:thread_id][cOh][i:page]?/[s:slug]'`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for the help. My custom match type cOh is now registered (I can see it when I print_r the $router variable). Unfortunately, my URL now looks like `/forum/24981[cOh]/my-super-forum-thread` when no page number is specified, and `/forum/24981[cOh]2/my-super-forum-thread` when a page number is specified